# PHP fsockopen() fails does not open port but telnet works

Tags: php, sockets, serial-port

I am facing a weird network problem trying to resolve for the last 2 days. I can not get to open the port 25003 on php web page. The code does not seem to be a problem, however, its as given below.

```html
$host = 'xx.xx.xx.xx';    // statis public ip address assigned by my isp
$ports = array(80, 25003);

foreach ($ports as $port)
{
    $connection = fsockopen($host, $port);

    if (is_resource($connection))
    {
        echo '<h2>' . $host . ':' . $port . ' ' . '(' . getservbyport($port, 'tcp') . ') is open.</h2>' . "\n";

        fclose($connection);
    }

    else
    {
        echo '<h2>' . $host . ':' . $port . ' is not responding.</h2>' . "\n";
    }
}
```

Port 80 shows open but not port 25003.

The site is hosted on Bluehost shared hosting plan with a static IP too. Cross verified with them more than 3 times the fact that port 25003 is open on both incoming and outgoing connections. Would they be lying, I don't think so.

On client PC settings :

```
(1) Firewall is disabled for testing purpose.

(2) Port forwarding is done correctly in router. I assume so because
 I can easily telnet MY PUBLIC IP with a port 25003 within the same
 LAN and from phone using sim card's internet.

(3) I did a port check from https://ping.eu/port-chk/ and it shows open.

(4) Client PC has a serproxy installed for serial to IP & Port.
(5) When I do a port check from above link, serproxy shows following message which seems to be okay on its part.
      * server thread launched
      * server(1) - thread started
      * server(1) - EOF from sock
      * server(1) - Exiting

(6) Again, when I telnet from external lan, it shows above message in Client PC's Serproxy which means it is doing its work properly. And it shows correct data from serial port to cmd line while telneting.
```

The problem is when I fsockopen using above pieces of code, it says CONNECTION REFUSED.

Below is my actual code which should try to connect and read data from serial port but CONNECTION REFUSED.

```html
$fp = fsockopen("tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx", 25003, $errno, $errstr);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    if (!feof($fp)) {
        $weight = trim(fgets($fp, 64)," ");
    }
}
echo $weight;
 fclose($fp);
```

I think the problem lies either in bluehost shared server or client windows PC or SERPROXY or local network configuration. I am afraid there is any major config change possible other than baud rate, com port etc in the SERPROXY which is set correctly.

I am now totally clueless as to how to resolve the said problem. If somebody could help will be greatly appreciated.

I would share the public IP if somebody wants to check the connectivity.

Comment: seems to work for me ( using ip from previous question )

Comment: @RamRaider Any hints, where the problem could be ?

Comment: no - I tried before and all attempts to connect were refused ( unable to connect etc ) but now using the above method and also a previous attempt ( socket_create, socket_connect etc ) seems ok

Comment: @RamRaider  Should I assume that the problem lies with Bluehost? Because if it works with you, it should work with mine as well, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned - previously when I attempted to connect all attempts failed but both methods below now work so I'd assume the problem is fixed. I'd maybe suggest restarting the webserver and browser(s)

```
<?php
    set_time_limit( 0 );
    error_reporting( E_ALL );

    $address = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
    $port = 25003;


    /* Method #1 */
    $fp = fsockopen( "tcp://{$address}", 25003, $errno, $errstr );
    if( !$fp ) echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
    else {
        if( !feof( $fp ) ) {
            $weight = trim(fgets($fp, 64)," ");
        }
    }
    printf('<h1>Method #1</h1>Weight: %s<br /><br />',$weight);
    fclose($fp);




    /* Method #2 */
    function geterror(){
        $obj=new stdClass;
        $obj->code=socket_last_error();
        $obj->error=socket_strerror( $obj->code );
        return $obj;
    }
    function negotiate( $socket ) {
        socket_recv( $socket, $buffer, 1024, 0 );

        for( $chr = 0; $chr < strlen( $buffer ); $chr++ ) {
            if( $buffer[ $chr ] == chr( 255 ) ) {
                $send = ( isset( $send ) ? $send . $buffer[$chr] : $buffer[$chr] );

                $chr++;
                if( in_array($buffer[$chr], array(chr(251), chr(252))) ) $send .= chr(254);
                if( in_array($buffer[$chr], array(chr(253), chr(254))) ) $send .= chr(252);

                $chr++;
                $send .= $buffer[$chr];
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        if( isset($send)) socket_send($socket, $send, strlen($send), 0);
        if( $chr - 1 < strlen($buffer)) return substr($buffer, $chr);
    }



    $socket = socket_create( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP );


    try{

        if( $socket && is_resource( $socket ) ){
            if( !socket_connect( $socket, $address, $port ) ){
                $err=geterror();
                throw new Exception( sprintf( 'socket_connect: %s', $err->error ), $err->code );
            } else {

                while( true ){

                    $e=null;
                    $w=null;
                    $r = array( $socket );
                    $c = socket_select( $r, $w, $e, 5 );

                    foreach( $r as $read_socket ) {
                        if( $r = negotiate( $read_socket ) ) {
                            exit( sprintf( '<h1>Method #2</h1>Reading: %s', print_r( $r, true ) ) );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {
            $err=geterror();
            throw new Exception( sprintf( 'Failed to create socket: %s',$err->error ), $err->code );
        }

    }catch( Exception $e ){
        printf( "
        <pre>
            <h1>Error: %d</h1>\nMessage: %s\nTrace: %s\nLine: %d
        </pre>",$e->getCode(),$e->getMessage(),$e->getTraceAsString(),$e->getLine() );
    }
    socket_close( $socket );
?>
```

[image: output from the two methods shown]

Comment: Thank you, it means the problem lies in bluehost. When contacted bluehost, they refused to restart the webserver as I am in a shared hosting. Is there anything else in particular I must ask them since sockets are not working only in buehost.

Comment: try running the above code ( with correct ip ) on your LOCAL / Dev webserver...does it work for you then?

Comment: Using the above fsockopen code, I can now successfully get the data but I was wondering if I could get the weight flicker on my webpage in realtime as it changes in the weighing scale indicator. Is it possible ? Any hints, how can I go about it ? Btw, thanks a lot for your answer, it made me confident that the problem was with Bluehost, though unresolved until now as they say that they are working on it to resolve. It works absolutely fine in my local server and from another A2 hosting site.